# How to find and eliminate sources of randomness in a Java program

Tags: java, random

I'm currently working on a genetic programming algorithm in Java.
For my experiments I'm trying several setting combinations and to get an idea of the time required I run every setting combination several times so I can take the average etc.

However, even though I only initiate one Random rng instance with a constant value as a seed sometimes (not always unfortunately) I get different results for runs with the same settings.

So, my question is, what could other sources of randomness be, except the explicit creation of new random number generators in my own code?

Could it be in the way sets, hashing, etc. etc. work??? And how could I make those work predictable?

I already checked for calls to Collections.shuffle and made them seed with my single Random instance...

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Some comments suggest to post code. However, I'm not seeking for specific feedback but I'm more interested to know in general what (undesired) sources of randomness can be. One that I forgot to mention is of course the use of multiple threads.

Of course I forcefully make my code run single threaded to prevent any randomness from that source

Comment: If you have multiple threads the order in which they pull the random numbers can vary between runs.

Comment: You'll have to show some code

Comment: Without examining your code, all we can speculate is that your program runs in parallel and the threads are working in different orders each run. Post some code.

Comment: re:update Is your implementation multithreaded then ? Because that would be a source of randomness.

Comment: If you're running on a multi-machine environment, different machines/OS's may produce different random number streams.  But my money's on the multi-thread suggestion.

Comment: Even if it is multi-threaded, you *may* be able to make your program deterministic with the use of various classes from the Java Concurrency API.

Comment: Indeed, forgot to mention that, as far as I know, I force my code to run single threaded during experiments. Will update post.

Comment: If using Swing, see also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 2):

Once you have eliminated Random and multi-threading as sources of non-determinism, the next place to look is forgetting to implement hashCode() and equals() on some object that is used in collections. I never use Random for anything, but I have had many a non-deterministic program whose nefarious behavior could be traced to Object.hashCode().

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of random numbers generated with java.util.Random is guaranteed to be the same for any specific seed used to initialize it. From [the API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html):

> If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the
>   same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and
>   return identical sequences of numbers.

So the short answer is that this can only happen if you are changing either the number or sequence of method calls made against the RNG. The most likely explanation, as has been mentioned in the comments, is that you have multiple threads using the RNG. In this case, it is obviously possible for the nondeterministic OS scheduling to cause the calling sequence to be different from run to run.

Another way this could happen, even in a single threaded application, is if your application uses the RNG - directly or indirectly - from any event handlers that are not strictly ordered. For example, if you (or a library you use) use `Random` from an event handler for mouse, keyboard, or network events, the nondeterministic ordering in which these events are handled could alter the sequence of numbers generated by your otherwise mainline code.

Comment: So there are 2 causes for randomness: using random number creators from different sources/different seeds and multi-threading? Things like sets, hashcodes (should not) etc. should not be another cause?

Comment: @JoosBuijs I'm not sure what you mean by "using random number creators from different sources" but the gist of what you say is correct -- using sets, hashcodes, etc., should not introduce any randomness into the sequence of numbers produced by the java.util.Random random number generator (even if you are are, e.g., putting different elements into those collections on different runs). The seed really determines *the* sequence of numbers that will be generated -- this sequence will *always* be generated for a given same sequence of method calls.

Comment: I was not suggesting that some behavior (e.g. working with sets etc.) influenced the results of a random number generator (rng). I was just curious what I should look for if my code behaved differently between runs with the same settings. I checked that I use the same rng instance throughout my code (I know that this is not absolutely necessary, as long as you use don't use 'strong'/unpredictable rng's). Furthermore, checking for multiple threads running, call to methods such as Collections.shuffle without passing your own rng etc. can influence results. That is what I was looking for.